# This problem has two answers, which one is correct?

Tags: geometry

[image: This is the picture]

Let $BC=a,AC=b,$ and $ AB=c$.

Now, In between $\triangle BCE$ and $\triangle ADC$,

$\angle ADC=\angle BEC=90 ^{\circ}$

$\angle ACB=\angle BCA$ [$\because$ They are common angles]

$remaining\angle EBC=remaining\angle DAC$

So the triangles are similar.

So $\frac{AC}{BC}=\frac{CD}{CE}=\frac{b}{a}$

$\therefore \frac{CD}{CE}=\frac{b}{a}$

Again, from the extension of Pythagoras's theorem we get,

$c^2=a^2 +b^2-2b\cdot CD$......(i)

$c^2=a^2+b^2-2a\cdot CE$.......(ii)

Now from (i) and (ii) we get,

$b\cdot CD =a\cdot CE$

$\frac{CD}{CE}=\frac{a}{b}$

But we previously saw otherwise, $\frac{CD}{CE}=\frac{b}{a}$
so which one of the answers is correct?

Comment: @lulu I edited it

Comment: (i) and (ii) are not OK. It is $CE$ in (i) and $CD$ in (ii). Since $c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos C$ and $b\cos C= CD$ from triangle $ACD$. And the other one is similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably made a mistake when applying the extension of Pythagoras's theorem.

From the law of cosines,

$$c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos\angle C$$

By substituting $CD=AC\cos\angle C=b\cos\angle C$, we get

$$c^2=a^2+b^2-2a\cdot CD......(1)$$

By substituting $CE=BC\cos\angle C=a\cos\angle C$, we get

$$c^2=a^2+b^2-2b\cdot CE......(2)$$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$, we get

\begin{align}
a\cdot CD &=b\cdot CE \\
\frac{CD}{CE} &= \frac{b}{a}
\end{align}

which is the same result obtained by using similar triangles.

Comment: Oh yeah, I got it